# How to access a certain cell of a named range with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, named-ranges

I have opened an Excel file with Python 3.8  / openpyxl and I am trying to access a certain cell of a named range
`wb.defined_names['name']` with the address `'Daten!$C$4:$E$2000'`

What I want to do is something like this Excel VBA code:
`[name].cells(i, 2)`to enter the cell in row i and column 2 of that range 'name', which would be 'D6' for i=3.

The obvious solution doesn't work:
`wb.defined_names['name'].cell(i,2)`

There must be an easier solution than picking the address of the range and modify it...
`ws[list(wb.defined_names['name'].destinations)[0][1].replace(....)]`

Comment: You can convert the range to coordinates and then access the cells.

Comment: How can I convert the range to coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

maybe try something like this:

```
from openpyxl.reader.excel import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(r'path\to\your\file.xlsx')
ws = wb['YourSheet']

ws.cell(i, j).value #to get the value from the cell
```

Now you can iterate over rows/columns.

If you need to get the total amount of rows/columns use:

```
rows = ws.max_row
cols = ws.max_column
```

Take care, friend

edit:

A simple and easy solution would be:

```
for i in range(ws.max_rows): #iterate over all rows
    for j in range(ws.max_cols): #iterate over all columns
        if ws.cell(i, j).value == 'yourCriteria':
            print('execute my code here')
```

In the range() function you can specifify where to start your range e.g.:

```
for i in range(2, ws.max_rows): #it would go from cell 2 to the end of the rows
```

Comment: The point is that I don't know the abolute address of the cell in the sheet. I know the coordinates of the cell relative to the range, but I am not interested in where the range is located within the sheet. I wonder if there is a reasonable way to access the cell, if  I only have the relative position of the cell in the range without the detour to extract the range's address and construct the absolute cell address.

Comment: A simple and easy solution would be:
for x in range(ws.max_rows): #iterate over all rows

Comment: I thought about that, but I didn't want to crawl through the whole range.